# What dump file options or MariaDB setting is slowing down the load of data?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysqldump

**Context:** 
Loading a copy of a legacy DB for a CRUD app at build by Spring Boot. Primary use case is developers testing the CRUD functionality as it is developed.

**Problem:** 
The loading operation is still over 2 minutes (1.57GB total DB size) but it seems like it should be much faster on a MBP with flash memory. I need to get it faster if at all possible but I don't know:
1. What property/config I am missing?
2. If my expectations are unrealistic?

**Tried:** 
1. Lots of different combinations of mysqldump options. No effect.
2. Resizing the number of dump files, up to an including 1 dump file for each of the 557 tables. Shaves 2-5 seconds off at best.

**Current Settings**

```
mariaDb.getConfiguration().addArg("--innodb_doublewrite=0");
mariaDb.getConfiguration().addArg("--innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2");
mariaDb.getConfiguration().addArg("--innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2");
mariaDb.getConfiguration().addArg("--max_allowed_packet=536870912");
mariaDb.getConfiguration().addArg("--innodb-buffer-pool-size=536870912");
```

**Details:**
I have the following dump files...

[image]

each of which was generated with mysqldump using the following options...

```
"--no-create-info", "--no-autocommit", "--single-transaction"
```

...and starts like...

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.16, for osx10.11 (x86_64)
--
-- Host: 127.0.0.1    Database: productdb
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.7.18

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `productdata`
--

LOCK TABLES `productdata` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `productdata` DISABLE KEYS */;
set autocommit=0;
INSERT INTO `productdata` VALUES (0,1954,'32814500',NULL),(0,2113,'Default',NULL),(10005,1000,'$19.99',NULL), more more more
INSERT INTO `productdata` VALUES (0,1954,'32814500',NULL),(0,2113,'Default',NULL),(10005,1000,'$19.99',NULL), more more more
```

It should be noted that this is a legacy system, so most of these dump files are <5 tables, and 1 of them has over 500 tables. So, for instance dump1 (shown) is a single 162 MB table with 4 columns. It has 161 multi-insert statements, each of which is 42,136 inserts "wide" in the sql file. **Is it possible that parsing the SQL is the limiting factor here?**

They are ALL InnoDB tables and I am using the following Java 8 code as part of Spring Boot to load the DB at build...

```
@Bean
@DependsOn(DB_SERVICE)
DataSource dataSource(MariaDB4jSpringService mariaDB4jSpringService) {

    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    //Create our database with default root user and no password
    try {
        DB db = mariaDB4jSpringService.getDB();
        db.source("productdb_schema.sql");
        db.run("SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=1073741824;");
        db.run("SET GLOBAL innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2;");

        ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(cl);
        List<Resource> sqlFiles = Arrays.asList(resolver.getResources("classpath*:/LegacyDumps/*.sql"));
        sqlFiles.parallelStream().forEach(sqlFile -> {
            try {
                db.source("LegacyDumps/" + sqlFile.getFilename(), dataSourceUser, dataSourcePassword, databaseName);
            }
            catch (ManagedProcessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long duration = (endTime - startTime);
        System.out.println("Loading Product DB took " + duration / 1000000000 + " seconds");
    }

    DBConfigurationBuilder config = mariaDB4jSpringService.getConfiguration();
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().username(dataSourceUser).password(dataSourcePassword).url(config.getURL(databaseName)).driverClassName(datasourceDriver).build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may consider

1. [disabling `innodb_doublewrite`](https://www.percona.com/blog/2006/08/04/innodb-double-write/)
2. restarting the database.
3. inserting the rows,
4. re-enabling it.
5. restarting the database.

Get back to us if you try it. I'd like to know the speedup.

Comment: I'm not sure how to edit properties that are normally in the my.cnf file, as this is a Spring Bean.

Comment: With these settings:
  mariaDb.getConfiguration().addArg("--innodb_doublewrite=0");
  mariaDb.getConfiguration().addArg("--innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2");
  mariaDb.getConfiguration().addArg("--innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2");
  mariaDb.getConfiguration().addArg("--max_allowed_packet=536870912");
  mariaDb.getConfiguration().addArg("--innodb-buffer-pool-size=536870912");
I got 139 seconds. :(